# How to set a global variable in Browser scope .wait(fn) NightmareJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, nightmare

I want to set a global variable based on the web I am scraping. However, I was able to do this only with .evaluate and .then. This is not what I need, because I wasn't able to run anything after that.

Thanks for the Help! :)

```js
var global;

nightmare
.goto(url)
.wait(() => {
  global = document.getElementById("element").textContent;
})
.click()
.wait()
.more...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

People will tell you not to do things with global variables. I guess you just want to store and use some data in some small script. There are several ways to save the variable for later use. I won't go thru database and stuff like that for now.

## Window Object inside the Nightmare instance

You can use window object since it will be there as long as you are same page and don't refresh the page.

```
await nightmare
.goto(url)
.evaluate(() => {
  window.aGlobalVariable = document.getElementById("element").textContent;
})
```

and then later you can call it later as long you are in same page.

```
await nightmare
.evaluate(() => {
  console.log(`${aGlobalVariable} looks tasty`);
})
```

## Saving and passing the variable between contexts

```
let aGlobalVariable;
aGlobalVariable = await nightmare
.goto(url)
.evaluate(() => {
  return document.getElementById("element").textContent;
})
```

Now you can access aGlobalVariable from the nodeJS context.
Whenever you want it inside nightmareJS again, you can pass it to the browser again if you want.

```
await nightmare
.goto(url)
.evaluate((aGlobalVariable) => { // <-- call it in the function
  console.log(`${aGlobalVariable} looks tasty.`)
}, aGlobalVariable) // <-- pass it here
```

Make sure you know about async await and promises, otherwise you will end up getting weird errors when running these codes.

Here are some references for that.

- https://ponyfoo.com/articles/understanding-javascript-async-await

Comment: @BertramSkarupa If it worked, choose it as answer so it will not show in unanswered searches. Otherwise tell me what did not work :)

Comment: I was unable to get it working. Could you please send me a small example script it would help very much! thank you :)

Comment: Ok this is my code https://pastebin.com/jgTzL9GT       Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

you can set global variables and access them in the evaluate function

```
const p1 = 1;
const  p2 = 2;

nightmare
  .evaluate(
    function (param1, param2) {
      //now we're executing inside the browser scope.
      return param1 + param2;
    },
    p1,
    p2 
  )
  .end();
```